I have found the maximum value of $|z-i|$ to be $\dfrac{9}{4}$ but I am unable to think of a way to solve for $\arg(z)$.
If $z$ satisfies the relation $|z –( (a^2 – 7a + 11) + i)| = 1$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$, and also $\arg(z)\ge\dfrac{\pi}{2}$  is satisfied by at least one $z$. Then the value of $\arg(z)$ for which $|z – i|$ is maximum is
(A) $\pi – \arctan(4/9)$
(B) $\pi – \arctan(9/4)$
(C) $\pi – \arctan(1/9)$
(D) $\pi – \arctan(4/5)$
I have found maximum of $|z-i|$ to be 9/4.
The minimum of a²-7a +11 is -5/4. So using the property |z-w|>=|z|-|w|, I get maximum of |z-i| to be 9/4
.i.e. |z-i|= 9/4. So Shouldn't there be multiple values of $\arg(z)$ since $z$ is a locus of circles, such that $\arg(z)\ge\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Only one $z$ on the circle is described by "for which $|z-i|$ is maximum". As you found, this means $|z-i|=\frac 94$.

@aschepler how do I find arg(z) from this

You can find $z$ itself. It would help to give you the best answer if you edit your question to include what you've already done to find the maximum $|z-i|=\frac 94$. (And important info like that should be included in the question body, not the title only.)

@aschepler since z is a locus of circle centred at (0,1) and r=9/4, there can be multiple z satisfying arg(z) >= π/2. So how can I find one particular z here?

Yes, knowing only $|z-i| = \frac 94$ is certainly not enough to determine $z$. But don't toss out the other things you already know. In particular, what's $a$, and the circle involving $a$ from the original question?

@aschepler I have given you the full question. There is nothing more I can add to this

The other information you need to find $z$ is $|z-((a^2-7a+11)+i)|=1$. What values can $a$ or $a^2-7a+11$ have when $|z-i|=\frac 94$ is satisfied?
